# check dns-blacklist of ip by using namp

Tags: nmap

I'm talking about this script for nmap
http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/dns-blacklist.html

User Summary

Checks target IP addresses against multiple DNS anti-spam and open proxy blacklists and returns a list of services for which an IP has been flagged. Checks may be limited by service category (eg: SPAM, PROXY) or to a specific service name.

Does it possible to use [Timing and Performance](http://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html) of nmap like make it in parallel and set time out? any example please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dns-blacklist` script uses the [`dnsbl`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/lib/dnsbl.html) library to perform queries. That library uses Lua [coroutines](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.6) to issue many requests in parallel. The number of coroutines (including scripts) that can be running at any given time is set by the `CONCURRENCY_LIMIT` variable in nse_main.lua, and is not settable by the user. A more complete description of NSE parallelism can be found [in the online documentation](http://nmap.org/book/nse-parallelism.html#nse-parallelism-threads).

For timeouts, the script itself does not accept a timeout script-argument. Fortunately, though, the `dnsbl` library offloads the DNS query execution to the [`dns`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/lib/dns.html) library, which has a function called `get_default_timeout`:

```
get_default_timeout = function()
  local timeout = {[0] = 10000, 7000, 5000, 4000, 4000, 4000}
  return timeout[nmap.timing_level()] or 4000
end
```

This shows that the `dns` library will set the timeout for DNS queries to 4000 ms (4 seconds) for `-T3` (the default) through `-T5`, but will be more cautions at lower timing levels.